# Is there a library to draw logic gates on Java

Tags: java, logic

I've created a program that reduces logical expression (can be found at http://sourceforge.net/projects/ksbe/).

It reduces the expression and show the reduced form and its truth table in HTML component. I want to add the possibility to show the diagram of the expression. Is there a library to help me to draw the diagram and get the result in image file (png or jpg) to show it in the HTML component?

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: I was using logic blocks in a program I was writing and it's not that difficult to get the images off the internet then just use those images as you would any other

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Logisim](http://ozark.hendrix.edu/~burch/logisim/) is an Open Source project from which you may get inspiration